# Multiple select in one table

Tags: mysql

My question is how to select using multiple select query in one table using PHP and MySQL. I tried with distinct or union but nothing !

Here is a part from the table :

```
ticket|amount
1357  | 5 
1357  | 5 
1356  | 10 
1356  | 10 
1356  | 10 
1355  | 5 
1355  | 5 
1355  | 5 
1354  | 5 
1354  | 5
```

I need the result like this

```
1357 -> 5 
1356 -> 10 
1355 -> 5 
1354 -> 5

total tickets -> 4 
total_amount -> 25
```

Comment: have you got PHP part to show too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(`ticket` AS CHAR(10)) AS ticket,`amount` FROM Table1 
GROUP BY `ticket`,`amount`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total tickets' AS ticket,COUNT(*) as amount 
FROM (
        SELECT CAST(`ticket` AS CHAR(10)) AS ticket,`amount` FROM Table1
        GROUP BY `ticket`,`amount`
     ) T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total_amount' AS ticket,SUM(amount) as amount 
FROM (
        SELECT CAST(`ticket` AS CHAR(10)) AS ticket,`amount` FROM Table1
        GROUP BY `ticket`,`amount`
     ) T2
```

**Output**

```
ticket          amount
1354            5
1355            5
1356            10
1357            5
total tickets   4
total_amount    25
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03a0d/47

Comment: it works but is shows ticket 1 in every ticket not ticket 1357 or 1356

Answer (score 1):

seems  you are looking for max(), count() and sum() by ticket

```
  select ticket, max(amount), count(*), sum(amount)
  from my_table  
  group by ticket
```

or   if you need  the sum of max value

```
select count(*), sum(my_max)
from (
  select ticket, max(amount) my_max, count(*), sum(amount) 
  from my_table  
  group by ticket ) t
```

Comment: your first answer is close to my problem 
but it shows me the for the ticket 1355 amount 15 
i want it once like 1355 amount 5

Answer (score 0):

Below code works in oracle, cast operator is used so that I can do union to get the text in output.

```
select distinct ticket ticket,cast (amount as varchar2(200)) as amount
from test_ticket 
union
select 'number of ticket->'|| cast(count(ticket) as varchar2(200)) as  
ticket,'sum of amount->'||sum(amount) as amount
from (
select distinct ticket,amount
from test_ticket);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need with `->` is an associative array ? In this case make it like this :

```
SELECT `ticket`, `amount` FROM `test_ticket` GROUP BY `ticket`, `amount`
```

And here is PHP code to create the array you need :

```
// query and constuct array
if($data = $db->query($q) {
    if($arr = $data->fetchAll(MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($arr as $res) {
            $output[$res['ticket']]  = $res['amount'];
            $output['total_tickets'] ++;
            $output['total_amount']  += $res['amount'];
        }
    }
}

// to print the array
print_r($output);
```